# In SQL 2000 how do you determine what process slows down the server

Tags: sql-server

Sql Server 2000 is maxed out, and I am not sure why, but I believe it may be due to the fact that a query or queries were run that are slowing it down.  Is there a way to determine which query caused the slow down, and at what time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, if you have the Enterprise Manager tool, you can do a "Profile trace" with that.  Then, after you have traced the queries, you can analyze the data manually (with your own eyes)  or you can use the SQL Analyzer tool to actually analyze individual queries (using Show Execution Plan ??)  and get detailed info on their performance.  (this is not possible using SQL Express versions or MSDE )

Comment: I have sql 2000, but I'm also using Sql 2008 R2 management studio tool.  Is it possible to get that to work with SQL Server 2000 with regard to the profile feature?

Answer (score 1):

[SQL Server Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa173918%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)

Comment: This tool is only necessary if your running SQL Express versions of 2005 and 2008. If you have FULL versions of SQL Server or SQL2000, those versions have the Microsoft version of the Profiler tool already included.

Comment: He said he has 2000. He wants to see performance ... Profiler was the best tool in 2000 to do that.  Where did I mention Express, 2005 or 2008?

Answer (score 1):

A quick check for blocking - not sure where I picked this up (might be K Delaney):

IF exists
(select * from master.dbo.sysprocesses
where spid IN(select blocked from master.dbo.sysprocesses))
select spid, status, loginame=substring(loginame,1,12),
hostname=substring(hostname,1,12), blk=CONVERT(char(3), blocked),
dbname=substring(DB_NAME(dbid),1,10), cmd, waittype
from master.dbo.sysprocesses where spid in
(select blocked from master.dbo.sysprocesses) and blocked = 0
else
  select 'No blocking process found'

Comment: ahhh, so if the process is blocking its still running on the server?  I think sp_locks,  and the sp_who2 thing is also something else I discovered on this, thanks.

Comment: Yep, the BlkBy column in sp_who2 will get you thre too.